# How to make small menu selection dropdown scroll a large list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I needed to create a menu system that would allow a small dropdown, and then a scrolling option to see the list of options, that exceed the menu dropdown window size.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resource at https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/

However, this is greatly out of date, as it has `.hover`
It has now been replaced with mouse enter.

Here's how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/y7axvw31/

To get it working you can use the following:

```js
let maxHeight = 300;

    $(function(){

        $(".dropdown > li").on('mouseenter',function() {

            let $container = $(this),
                $list = $container.find("ul"),
                $anchor = $container.find("a"),
                height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
                multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

            // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout
            $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

            // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
            $anchor.addClass("hover");

            // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item
            $list
                .show()
                .css({
                    paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
                });

            // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
            if (multiplier > 1) {
                $container
                    .css({
                        height: maxHeight,
                        overflow: "hidden"
                    })
                    .on("mousemove",(function(e) {
                        let offset = $container.offset();
                        let relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                        if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                            $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                        }
                    }));
            }

        });
        $(".dropdown > li").on('mouseleave',function() {

            let $el = $(this);

            // put things back to normal
            $el
                .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
                .find("ul")
                .css({ top: 0 })
                .hide()
                .end()
                .find("a")
                .removeClass("hover");

        });
    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

/*
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}

ul.dropdown li {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 8px;
  color: #222;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ul.dropdown li a:hover,
ul.dropdown li a.hover {
  background: #F3D673;
  position: relative;
}


/*
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.dropdown ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: #eee !important;
}

ul.dropdown ul li a:hover {
  display: block;
  background: #F3D673 !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">Main Category</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">six</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">seven</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```